# how to perform non-persistent XSS attach to a simple php search field

Tags: php, xss

I have a php search field that searches for the users inside the database and outputs in in a table.

I wanted to learn how to perform a simple non-persistent XSS attack to the search field.

This is my php:

```
echo "List of user(s) found:<br><br>";

    $query = "select display_name, email from members where user_name='".$_POST['search_name']."';";

    $res = mysqli_query($Connect,$query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0 )
    {
     echo "<table border=1>";
     echo "<tr><th>Display Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
     {
      echo "<tr><td>$row[display_name]</td><td>$row[email]</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "User not found!";
    }
```

I have tried sending through some background change syntax and alerts but none seem to work.

```
<div style="background:<?php echo $colour ?>;">
<script>alert(‘XSS injection’)</script>
```

Can someone explain to me how I would manage any sort of attack?

NB: I would like it to be a POST method and not GET

Thank you.

Comment: You can inject data into the query in such a way that it gets added as rows to the result, which would then be injected into the HTML. Blammo - double-injection

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to understand how they work, then you could post something like this:

```
$_POST['search_name'] = "' OR 1=1 UNION SELECT '<script>alert(\"XSS Injection\");</script>', '";
```

That would allow you to inject XSS into the page, and get all usernames/emails.

**e:** The resulting query would look like this:

```
select display_name, email from members where user_name='' OR 1=1 UNION SELECT '<script>alert(\"XSS Injection\");</script>', '';
```

The result would look like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this wouldn't work. For one thing there is no `like`. Another thing it isn't just going to output what is returned. You'd need to give that an alias and give it the same column assignment as the previous select.

Comment: yeah, that's a fair point. The XSS will still work, though. - e: edited so that it doesn't rely on 'LIKE' and still has the same result

Comment: Ok so your code does actually have an effect. It retrieves all the users and puts them on the table. The alert though never happens!

Comment: The value would need to be aliased.

Comment: Not really, the union would just put results in the same columns

Comment: Lets say there is a password field but not outputted on the php markup, would it be possible to have an injection that would output the password field as well?

Comment: Pretty easily. You just update the union select to select... well.. whatever you wanted (pretty standard SQL injection). Passwords shouldn't be stored as plain text, though (but let's face it - if there are SQL injection vulnerabilities, passwords probably won't be hashed)